# Recover deleted file by inode

Tags: terminal, filesystem, file

I had a crazy file named ''$\r' that I wanted to delete by inode. So I googled how to do it and found an example. Being half asleep and a few beers in, I typed in the inode in the example:

`find . -inum 4063242 -exec rm -i {} \;`

I have no idea what this file is. Hopefully it's not important. But if it is, is there any way to find and recover it?